# Gradle NOT finding my subdirectory to build

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I have an application with subdirectory(projects) inside this project like this

- My Application

  - Project a
  - Project b
  - Project c

etc...

I'm trying to build Project b from the root folder (My Application) using this command:

```
gradle :Project b:build
```

But I got this error message:

> ```
> * What went wrong:
> Project 'Project b' not found in root project 'MyApplication'.
>
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> ```

But if from **My Application** I do this using command line:

```
cd Project b
```

and then run the build

```
gradle build
```

It builds successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your `settings.gradle` file. You should avoid using spaces in Gradle project names and in file paths in general!

Comment: @lu.koerfer thanks for your help mate, but I found a way to do it. Check my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that there is no `settings.gradle` and that this is not a multi-project build. Using that would be better but given the original question, note that `-p` specifies the starting project for Gradle.

So in the `MyApplication` dir, consider:

`gradle -p "Project b" build`

Though it would be wise to (a) investigate multi-project builds (b) remove spaces from the path (as mentioned in a comment).

Comment: I'll take this as an answer as it worked for me. My previous workaround I'll left behind. Cheers mate, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing the building from the root to subdirectories. In case anyone needs it, this is what I did on the terminal:

```
cd MyApplication/Project b && gradle build
```

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a real solution, because it is not Gradle related at all. You should setup either a multi-project build (if the projects are related) or a composite build.